# List of Structures in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

Hello I want to learn about all the structures in Java
eg.
Hashtable
Arraylist

Can anyone give me a list of more so I can have a firm understanding of these data structures..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[java.util.Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

See the list of all known implementing classes, etc. And read all that Javadoc. Then, if you really want to understand, download Eclipse and browse the source code (the JDK classes are open source):

> Interface Collection
>
> All Superinterfaces:
>       Iterable
>
> All Known Subinterfaces:
>       BeanContext, BeanContextServices, BlockingDeque, BlockingQueue,
>   Deque, List, NavigableSet,
>   Queue, Set, SortedSet
>
> All Known Implementing Classes:
>       AbstractCollection, AbstractList, AbstractQueue, AbstractSequentialList,
>   AbstractSet, ArrayBlockingQueue,
>   ArrayDeque, ArrayList, AttributeList,
>   BeanContextServicesSupport,
>   BeanContextSupport,
>   ConcurrentLinkedQueue,
>   ConcurrentSkipListSet,
>   CopyOnWriteArrayList,
>   CopyOnWriteArraySet, DelayQueue,
>   EnumSet, HashSet, JobStateReasons,
>   LinkedBlockingDeque,
>   LinkedBlockingQueue, LinkedHashSet,
>   LinkedList, PriorityBlockingQueue,
>   PriorityQueue, RoleList,
>   RoleUnresolvedList, Stack,
>   SynchronousQueue, TreeSet, Vector

Per the commenter below, see [java.util.Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Interface Map
>
> Type Parameters:
>       K - the type of keys maintained by this map
>       V - the type of mapped values
>
> All Known Subinterfaces:
>       Bindings, ConcurrentMap, ConcurrentNavigableMap,
>   LogicalMessageContext, MessageContext,
>   NavigableMap, SOAPMessageContext,
>   SortedMap
>
> All Known Implementing Classes:
>       AbstractMap, Attributes, AuthProvider, ConcurrentHashMap,
>   ConcurrentSkipListMap, EnumMap,
>   HashMap, Hashtable, IdentityHashMap,
>   LinkedHashMap, PrinterStateReasons,
>   Properties, Provider, RenderingHints,
>   SimpleBindings, TabularDataSupport,
>   TreeMap, UIDefaults, WeakHashMap

The [Java Collections Framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/reference.html) contains the APIs you are researching, which I believe another poster mentioned.

Comment: Additionally, have a look at `java.util.Map` and its subinterfaces + implementations.

Answer (score 3):

They are called collections. You can learn more about them **[`here`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)**.